# Unable to fetch user details by an id given in a JSON string | Getting a Type error in Django

Tags: json, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to get a user's details (in a JSON string format) by providing a user id (also in a JSON string format)

**This is my model's code**

```
    class Description(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    description = models.ForeignKey(Description, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

This is the serializer Code

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from users.models import Description, Team, User

class DescriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Description
        fields = "__all__"

class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = "__all__"

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"
```

This is the views code

```
from urllib import response
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from users.models import User, Team, Description
from .serializers import UserSerializer, TeamSerializer, DescriptionSerializer

# describe user
@api_view(["GET"])
def describe_user(request):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.data["id"])
    serializer = UserSerializer(user)
    return JsonResponse(serializer, safe=False)
```

Whenever I enter a JSON data in the body of URL eg: {"id":"2"}
I get this error

[[TypeError at /describe/
Object of type UserSerializer is not JSON serializable]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0wrD.png)

Comment: Please post the error directly in your question as text. You can open the terminal where your app is running and copy the entire error message from there and then paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are passing the Serializer Object Itself..

Per: [rest-framework tut serialization](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/), It looks like you must specify `.data`
Their example:

```py
serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet)
serializer.data
# {'id': 2, 'title': '', 'code': 'print("hello, world")\n', 'linenos': False, 'language': 'python', 'style': 'friendly'}
```

It would lead to something like this:

```py
@api_view(["GET"])
def describe_user(request):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.data["id"])
    serializer = UserSerializer(user)

    # debuggers
    print(type(serializer), serializer)
    print(type(serializer.data), serializer.data)

    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```